# iOS IAP restore doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have the ios App with IAP. I buy product in sandbox as tester user and everything is Ok. I receive receipt and parce it.
Then I re-install the App, I'm trying to restore IAP and call

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

Next

```
paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue)
```

is called. Nothing restored. 
I suppose there must be call of

```
paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
```

but it is missing! The receipt also doesn't exist.

There must be transactions to restore (because if I buy product again StoreKit says that it is already purchased) What am I doing wrong?

UPD:

The product I want to restore is Non-renewable subscription. If this is the only kind of products to restore, Apple does not return transactions list. If there was another product purchased (for example, Non-Consumable) Apple returns full list of transactions...

Comment: Are you purchasing/restoring as a user that is set up as a sandbox tester in iTunesConnect? I've run into this problem when using my real apple id running the app that is currently in development. The problem "fixed" itself when I purchase/restored using an iTunesConnect sandbox tester.

Comment: @beyerss yes, i am using the same tester account

Comment: @beyerss I logged out in [settings - iTunes store] and when restoring in my App I entered tester's login/pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I request the receipt before restoring purchases:

```
let receiptRefreshRequest: SKRequest = SKReceiptRefreshRequest()
receiptRefreshRequest.delegate = self
receiptRefreshRequest.start()
```

Then after response I do the restoration

```
public func requestDidFinish(request: SKRequest) {
    if request == receiptRefreshRequest {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }
}
```