# iOS restore subscription button not always working

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store, subscription

I have an iOS app with a non-auto subscription. I added a restore button to the app to allow user to restore their subscription if they install the app on another phone. However users are experiencing unusual behavior.

Some users are able to restore their subscription, and for some the restore button does nothing, it seems like Apple never even calls the paymentQueue() callback.

I am calling,

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

I found this, seems to indicate you need to first call this?

```
let receiptRefreshRequest: SKRequest = SKReceiptRefreshRequest()
receiptRefreshRequest.delegate = self
receiptRefreshRequest.start()
```

[iOS IAP restore doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615629/ios-iap-restore-doesnt-work)

Also in our own testing after we subscribe we go to iPhone Settings/Apple ID/subscriptions and it is empty?? Or does Apple only manage auto-renew subscription, and you are on your own for non-auto subscriptions??

Another odd behavior is that I am storing the record of the subscription in iCloud, so from my understanding if the same user signs in on another phone they should still see their subscription, even without calling restore. But this does not seem to be the case?? Storing in iCloud does not even seem to work after restarting the app on the same phone?

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *storage = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
```

Comment: It is your responsibility for tracking and restoring non-renewing subscriptions.  Apple only handles restore of auto renewing subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

So we switched to managing the subscription tracking ourselves on our server.

"It is your responsibility for tracking and restoring non-renewing subscriptions. Apple only handles restore of auto renewing subscriptions."